# SQL Query Execution more than once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, design-patterns

I have 2 tables (A,B), and 1 query

My query is something like this

1. Read From A
2. Update B with this data from A
3. Using the updated table B, set final value of A.

Example execution can be find in below question:
[Proper way to keep a single data in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775845/proper-way-to-keep-a-single-data-in-sql-server)

Now since all the process is connected, this query should not be executed twice at the same time, or by 2 different users until the process ends. How do I prevent this ? Or does it already work securely like this?

Comment: how are tables related with each other?

Comment: @JohnWoo they are not related much, the tables are the same in the example that I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transaction lock :

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--select * from A
-- update B ....
--update A

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'   -- tables remain locked for 2 secs   hh:mm:ss

commit TRANSACTION
```

during the transaction execution, any try to read or write from/to tables will timeout...

Comment: what is the purpose of locking tables for 2 seconds? aren't they already locked until the transaction ends?

Comment: yes of course ! but this is an option, to keep lock alive for a period of time. for example in case that we want to insert exam questions and hide their table until 3:00 pm (on exam start time). before that time any student cant see the questions.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**
 u must use, some lock to lock the db while updating. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

psedo code for u:

```
 int x=(select val from tableB)+1
 query="update tableB set tableB.field="+x+"where......." 
 if query executed successfully:
   update tableA
```

Comment: you wrote 2nd line in my sql query, and what about 1st and 3rd lines ?

Comment: i think in this query contain all three together. isn't it?

Comment: I have 1 sql query and 3 different processes as I showed by line numbers in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that your table A and B must be having some `Primary Key` eg `EmployeeID`. In such case a simple solution is to create a table (say `Lock_Table`) which keeps a record of the `EmployeeID` beign modified.
So here you would need to go like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
1- Read EmployeeID From A   
2- Check if EmployeeID already exists in Lock_Table. If Yes then Quit Else insert that EmployeeID in Lock_Table
3- Update B with this data(EmployeeID in this case) from A   
4- Using the updated table B, set final value of A.   
5- Delete this EmployeeID from the Lock_Table   
 COMMIT TRANSACTION

On any error ROLLBACK the Transaction.
```

Hope it helps.